# AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'errorbar'

Tags: python, seaborn, errorbar, catplot

I am trying to **add the confidence interval 95%** on my graph. This code works just fine:

```
sns.catplot(data=df, x="read_level_1", y="sum_START", kind="box")
```

However, when I try the following line:

```
sns.catplot(data=df, x="read_level_1", y="sum_START", errorbar=("ci", 95))
```

It doesn't work, and I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no property 'errorbar'
```

Any advice, please?

Comment: Seaborn will automatically add error bars with a 95% confidence interval **if there are multiple observations** for a given category. Also, the default for [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) is `kind='strip'`, it should be `kind='bar'`. You should also update seaborn and matplotlib. `ci` is deprecated / removed. If you're using anaconda, do `conda update --all` at the anaconda prompt for the specific environment. Otherwise update with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace use of non-existing `errorbar` with `kind` and `ci` arguments respectively. So instead of:

```py
sns.catplot(data=df, x="read_level_1", y="sum_START", errorbar=("ci", 95))
```

write:

```py
sns.catplot(data=df, x="read_level_1", y="sum_START", kind="bar", ci=95)
```

BUT... `ci` seems to be [marked deprecated](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html), so I'd rather go for `barplot()` instead:

```py
sns.barplot(data=df, x="read_level_1", y="sum_START", ci=95)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `kind` for `catplot` is `strip` but only two kinds (`bar` and `point`) can show error bars and, hence, accept the `errorbar` parameter to control what is shown.  A 95% CI is the default value for both so you just need to add `kind="point"` to your call.